# Set delegate in a different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

I'm trying to write my first iPhone app and i'm having some trouble with a delegate.

I have a class that utilises the AVAudioPlayer to play some sound, I then have another class that I need to do something when that sound is complete. So I need this class to implement audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method of the audio player.

The problem is, I can't work out how to make my second class a delegate of the audio player that is a member of the first class. I created a method in the first class that takes a reference to a class and runs the setDelegate method on this, but the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method never gets called. However if I implement the audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying method in the first class, it gets called fine. How can I get audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying to be called in the second class?

So, the code I'm using to add the delegate, in the first class I have this method:

```
-(void) setAudioDelegate:(id)delegate{
    [audioPlayer setDelegate:delegate];
}
```

then in the second class i'm calling it from this

```
[class1 setAudioDelegate:self];
```

Comment: You say you've already tried assigning an instance of your 'second class' as the delegate of the AVAudioPlayer instance. Can you post the code you did to do that?

Comment: Nothing in that posted code looks wrong. Forgive the obvious questions, but you're sure both 'class1' and 'audioPlayer' are not nil at the time the setAudioDelegate: call is made?

Comment: This isn't enough info to determine anything. Can you confirm that the method is getting called? Can you confirm that `audioPlayer` is set to something meaningful when it is called? In what method is that `[class1 setAudioDelegate:self]` called? What does that class's `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:` method look like?

Comment: @imaginaryboy yep, it hadn't been intialised at that point, should stop looking for complicated answers. Thanks very much, works now.

Comment: Mind if I write that up as an answer and you accept it? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Confirm that both 'audioPlayer' and 'class1' are not nil at the time you attempt to set the audio delegate.

Answer (score 0):

The delegate works in one-to-one manner.
If you want relations between instances works in many-to-many or one-to-many manner, maybe you could study [NSNotification class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003701), or [Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i).